# iOS 6 vs iOS 7 development

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

I was given an iOS6 development book by someone so I could start learning iOS development. Then Apple released iOS7 and majorly changed the OS. Can I still use the iOS6 book or is it out dated for the way things are done with iOS7? I am not familiar enough with the language or OS to know how drastic the framework changes were.

Comment: you'll be fine if you just trying to get started. The language itself didn't change and most the workflow remains the same.

Comment: If you're a complete beginner then it doesn't matter much. You can still learn loads from the book. Regardless of the iOS version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can still use the book you are currently using. Most of it will remain the same. The UI elements might look a tad different. There will be a few APIs that will be deprecated (watch for compiler warnings that indicate so). There are also a few new APIs that you can make use of.

You can take a look at what's new in iOS 7 in the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html) by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Download the previous generation of Xcode, 4.6.3 rather than 5. Then your app can target iOS 5 or 6 (and later). What you see on screen will match what you see in your book.

If you're registered as an Apple Developer, you can [download previous versions of Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?q=xcode).

You may want to use older generations of Xcode to serve older devices. Using Xcode 5 lets you develop and test apps for iOS 6 or 7 (and maybe later). Using Xcode 4.6.3 lets you develop and test apps for iOS 5 or 6 (and forward compatible with iOS 7).

Tip: Running virtual Mac environments on your real Mac using products such as [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/), [Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/), or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) let you set up pristine separate development spaces where you can use different versions of Mac OS X and Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

iOS development never changes so dramatically. There are some changes. The are some `additions` and there are somethings which are removed (deprecation).

`Deprecation` - The removal of some features, classes, methods so that they aren't implemented in the latest version of the OS, however can be used for previous OSes.

I do understand that iOS 7 is quite different from iOS 6 in terms of visuals and overall UI.
However, the same programming techniques will apply to both.

So, to answer your question - You can still use your iOS 6 book.

To natively program for iOS 6, [sign up for the Apple Developer Programme](https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?&appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=//membercenter/index.action).

Go to Xcode Downloads and download Xcode 4.6.3 from that.

[Apple's release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html) showing what's changed in iOS 7 from iOS 6.